# how to align * in corner of text in text view in android

Tags: android, xml, string, textview

Normally when we give * before text i looks like (*hai) but when use in this same text in string file for text view it does not looks same. I want to set * in left upper corner in the textview. [image]

Normal setText("*Cleaning Fee Applies"); does not put the asterisk in the place where I wanted it.

I want output like attached screen shot.  Please give me solution guys.

Comment: you might need to use two textviews. The optimum solution however can be to use drawableleft

Comment: i can use two text view but how to align left upside corner in my text

Comment: In single textview it is not possible. You either use two textviews or use an image view and set a drawable before textview.

Comment: Please note that what you are asking is already the default behaviour for the asterisk character: *Cleaning Fee Applies

Answer (score 1):

I used this class to create a superscript:

```
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

/**
 * A Helper class to adjust the alignment in a textview or other text section,
 * used when SpannableStrings sets text dynamically.
 * 
 */
public class SuperscriptSpanAdjuster extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    double ratio = 0.5;

    public SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(double ratio) {
        this.ratio = ratio;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.baselineShift += (int) (p.ascent() * ratio);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint arg0) {
        arg0.baselineShift += (int) (arg0.ascent() * ratio);
    }
}
```

Then used it like this:

```
String temp = getString("*Cleaning Fee Applies");
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(temp);
s.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(3.0/5.0), 0, 1, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mytextView)).setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
text.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you explain how a method that transforms characters into asterisks (i.e.: masking a password) answers the question `how to align * in corner of text`?

Comment: As @DerGolem notes, this answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked. Please be sure to keep in mind that we expect answers to *specifically* address the question being asked. If there is code in the question, your answer should address that code itself.